My ESTA is set to expire in the middle of an upcoming trip to the US. What should I do?
An ESTA is valid for two years.
I am encountering the case where the validity is due to end in the middle of a travel to the United States I am planning. For example, let's say the ESTA expires on July 20, 2024, and my travel is planned from July 15 to July 25 of the same year.
Am I free to go, or should I make an early renewal of the ESTA? I do not know if it is possible.

While, as the answer below rightfully says, you don’t actually need to do anything as the ESTA only needs to be valid on the day you enter the US, you can renew an ESTA at any time, which actually means just applying for a new one. The latest ESTA always replaces any previous ones.

Could we assume that you will not go (during your US trip) in Canada, Mexico or on a cruise? Else you need the ESTA to continue the travel in US.

Good point that you can renew anytime without having to wait for previous one to expire. One of the things I doubted about. And mentioning cruises is correct - been there done that, on disembarkation you have to go through immigration again, which causes a long wait, even if you go straight to the airport and fly out of the country a few hours later. Because nearly all cruise ships leaving from the US stop at a foreign port.

What you should do is nothing. An ESTA only needs to be valid up to the day you enter the USA.

Do I need to apply for a new ESTA if my current travel authorization will expire while I'm in the United States?


No. ESTA travel authorization needs only to be valid upon arrival in the United States.

https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq
